# unable to modify NTPClient to use static IP address

Tags: esp8266, programming, time

I tried the example  File > Examples > ESP8266WiFi > NTPClient which requests the current time and it worked fine.  Then I tried to modify it so that the ESP8266 would have a static IP address on my home network.  I added the following lines before  **void setup()**

```
IPAddress staticIP(192, 168,   0, 159);
IPAddress  gateway(192, 168,   0,   1);
IPAddress   subnet(255, 255, 255,   0);
```

Then, in  **void setup()**     I added a line and commented out the original line like this

```
//  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
WiFi.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet);
```

After running the sketch after I did this, it connected to my home network without any problems (as it did before).  But this time, after it prints the message **sending NTP packet...** to the serial monitor, it just says **no packet yet**.  This process is repeated every 10 seconds, but it never comes back with the time.

My troubleshooting efforts have been to uncomment the original line and comment out the line I added above.  This restores the sketch to its working condition.  I have done this several times over the past three days and the same thing always happens.

If I subscribed to conspiracy theories, I might think that some DHCP zealots are behind this.  Unfortunately, I can't come up with a better explanation.  So to ask just one question, "How can I get my ESP8266-01, flashed with Arduino 1.8.10, running on a Windows 8.1 laptop, to have a static IP on my home network and fetch current NTP timestamps from the internet?

(for reference, this is the sketch in question)

```
/*

  Udp NTP Client

  Get the time from a Network Time Protocol (NTP) time server
  Demonstrates use of UDP sendPacket and ReceivePacket
  For more on NTP time servers and the messages needed to communicate with them,
  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

  created 4 Sep 2010
  by Michael Margolis
  modified 9 Apr 2012
  by Tom Igoe
  updated for the ESP8266 12 Apr 2015
  by Ivan Grokhotkov

  This code is in the public domain.

*/

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "peopleMightFreakIfIuseMyRealInfo"
#define STAPSK  "dontHaveAsecurityPanicAttack"
#endif

const char * ssid = STASSID; // your network SSID (name)
const char * pass = STAPSK;  // your network password

IPAddress staticIP(192, 168,   0, 159);
IPAddress  gateway(192, 168,   0,   1);
IPAddress   subnet(255, 255, 255,   0);

unsigned int localPort = 2390;      // local port to listen for UDP packets

/* Don't hardwire the IP address or we won't get the benefits of the pool.
    Lookup the IP address for the host name instead */
//IPAddress timeServer(129, 6, 15, 28); // time.nist.gov NTP server
IPAddress timeServerIP; // time.nist.gov NTP server address
const char* ntpServerName = "time.nist.gov";

const int NTP_PACKET_SIZE = 48; // NTP time stamp is in the first 48 bytes of the message

byte packetBuffer[ NTP_PACKET_SIZE]; //buffer to hold incoming and outgoing packets

// A UDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
WiFiUDP udp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
//  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Starting UDP");
  udp.begin(localPort);
  Serial.print("Local port: ");
  Serial.println(udp.localPort());
}

void loop() {
  //get a random server from the pool
  WiFi.hostByName(ntpServerName, timeServerIP);

  sendNTPpacket(timeServerIP); // send an NTP packet to a time server
  // wait to see if a reply is available
  delay(1000);

  int cb = udp.parsePacket();
  if (!cb) {
    Serial.println("no packet yet");
  } else {
    Serial.print("packet received, length=");
    Serial.println(cb);
    // We've received a packet, read the data from it
    udp.read(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE); // read the packet into the buffer

    //the timestamp starts at byte 40 of the received packet and is four bytes,
    // or two words, long. First, esxtract the two words:

    unsigned long highWord = word(packetBuffer[40], packetBuffer[41]);
    unsigned long lowWord = word(packetBuffer[42], packetBuffer[43]);
    // combine the four bytes (two words) into a long integer
    // this is NTP time (seconds since Jan 1 1900):
    unsigned long secsSince1900 = highWord << 16 | lowWord;
    Serial.print("Seconds since Jan 1 1900 = ");
    Serial.println(secsSince1900);

    // now convert NTP time into everyday time:
    Serial.print("Unix time = ");
    // Unix time starts on Jan 1 1970. In seconds, that's 2208988800:
    const unsigned long seventyYears = 2208988800UL;
    // subtract seventy years:
    unsigned long epoch = secsSince1900 - seventyYears;
    // print Unix time:
    Serial.println(epoch);


    // print the hour, minute and second:
    Serial.print("The UTC time is ");       // UTC is the time at Greenwich Meridian (GMT)
    Serial.print((epoch  % 86400L) / 3600); // print the hour (86400 equals secs per day)
    Serial.print(':');
    if (((epoch % 3600) / 60) < 10) {
      // In the first 10 minutes of each hour, we'll want a leading '0'
      Serial.print('0');
    }
    Serial.print((epoch  % 3600) / 60); // print the minute (3600 equals secs per minute)
    Serial.print(':');
    if ((epoch % 60) < 10) {
      // In the first 10 seconds of each minute, we'll want a leading '0'
      Serial.print('0');
    }
    Serial.println(epoch % 60); // print the second
  }
  // wait ten seconds before asking for the time again
  delay(10000);
}

// send an NTP request to the time server at the given address
void sendNTPpacket(IPAddress& address) {
  Serial.println("sending NTP packet...");
  // set all bytes in the buffer to 0
  memset(packetBuffer, 0, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
  // Initialize values needed to form NTP request
  // (see URL above for details on the packets)
  packetBuffer[0] = 0b11100011;   // LI, Version, Mode
  packetBuffer[1] = 0;     // Stratum, or type of clock
  packetBuffer[2] = 6;     // Polling Interval
  packetBuffer[3] = 0xEC;  // Peer Clock Precision
  // 8 bytes of zero for Root Delay & Root Dispersion
  packetBuffer[12]  = 49;
  packetBuffer[13]  = 0x4E;
  packetBuffer[14]  = 49;
  packetBuffer[15]  = 52;

  // all NTP fields have been given values, now
  // you can send a packet requesting a timestamp:
  udp.beginPacket(address, 123); //NTP requests are to port 123
  udp.write(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
  udp.endPacket();
}
```

Comment: I suspect you also need to specify your DNS server (usually the same as your gateway, or use 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 for the google public DNS servers)

Comment: @Majenko  THANK YOU!!! THANK YOU!!! THANK YOU!!! THANK YOU!!!                 That did the trick!  I added the gateway as dns1 and used 8.8.8.8 as dns2   Do you want to post your comment as an answer?  I'll accept it for sure, If not, should I add [SOLVED] to my question or answer my own question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as specifying your IP address and gateway you also have to provide DNS server addresses. These are normally provided by DHCP, and the ESP8266 *doesn't* assume that it's the same as your gateway address when using a static IP address.

Normally you would use your router's IP address as your DNS server address, but you can also use the Google public DNS servers on `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

The full format of the `config` function is:

```cpp
  WiFi.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet, dns);
```

where `dns` is, like the other parameters, an `IPAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Arduino IDE with <ESP8266WiFi.h> there is a different order for the arguments in the config-statement See the comment in the source code: //ESP argument order is: ip, gateway, subnet, dns1
//Arduino arg order is: ip, dns, gateway, subnet.

So after lots of trouble i changed my config in WiFi.config(STATICIP, DNS1, GATEWAY, SUBNET) and everything works smooth now. The comment means that if you use ESP-IDE (?) the argument order is: ip, gateway, subnet, dns1. When you use Aduino IDE (for ESP8266) the argument order is: ip, dns, gateway, subnet._

Comment: ESP-IDE? ESP WiFi library! the esp8266 WiFi library has the order of `config` parameters different than all other WiFi libraries and Ethernet libraries. but the esp8266 WiFi library's config function can detect the parameters and works with the common ordering too